# setting constants when config.assets.initialize_on_precompile is false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, asset-pipeline

Deploying on Heroku requires that `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile=false` in application.rb. From the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) it says that this "partially loads your application".

So I was wondering what the best practices were for setting some constants to be used in compiled assets (e.g. *.js.erb)? With this flag set to false I can't use anything that is set in initailizers. I'm not super clear on what parts of the application are loaded, and how I might be able to set any constants, variables etc before the compilation step is performed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar situation, fortunately I was able fix it easily. I knew that the `config.assets.initi....` was being executed on heroku as heroku docs ask for it. I just had to manually load my initializer files before that. I wanted just one `/config/initializers/settings.rb` file, so I added a require for that. And that fixed the problem.

```
...
#at the end of the /config/application.rb file
require Rails.root.join("config/initializers/settings") #this is not loaded automatically in the assets:precompile task, that's why we need this
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
...
```

Comment: If the constants you need are only used in one asset file, I prefer @akanet's solution because it's more obvious what your intentions are when you require the file from where it's needed.  Of course, when the same constants are needed in multiple asset files, you need to balance that concern with the goals of DRY and maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the cleanest solution I could come up with

`somejavascriptfile.js.erb`:

```
<%
  # get around no asset initialization in precompile
  require Rails.root.join('config/initializers/facebook')
%>

console.log('<%= Facebook::APP_ID %>');
```

`config/initializers/facebook.rb`

```
module Facebook
  CONFIG = YAML.load(File.open(Rails.root.join('config/facebook.yml')))[Rails.env]
  APP_ID = CONFIG['app_id']
  SECRET = CONFIG['secret']
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm somewhat new to the asset pipeline, so I'm not sure about best practices.  However, one solution that comes to mind is to add a rake task that is a dependency of assets:precompile.  I'm not quite sure what the taks would do though.  The implementation I'm imagining isn't very pretty.

You'd probably have to create template files, like *.js.erb.template that your rake task would copy to *.js.erb files and perform some kind of gsub on the file contents to replace some placeholders with constant values.

Hopefully someone else has a better method...